# My 3D model is always upside down when uploading to Facebook, no matter how I rotate it

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, 3d

I am trying to post a 3D model. I simplified the mesh so that it fits through the tiny 3MB limit and it's rendered OK.

[image]

Except... It's UPSIDE DOWN! I tried to upload model after rotating it in different direction, but the result is always the same. Upside down. The preview form does not allow me to rotate it more than some 180 degrees, so it's stuck upside down forever.

What can I do with the model to make it upside up instead?

Comment: What is the file format?  If it's a JPEG, Facebook might be trying to infer the orientation from non-existent EXIF data.

Comment: @jonsca It's a 3D model. Facebook only accepts one format of 3D models - GLB.